# Connecting multiple hard drives through one sata input

Tags: hard-drive, raid, sata

There is a surveillance system with one sata input, there are several hard drives that I would like to connect through this port with that
[sata hub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXUrd.png)

After a careful reading I came to the conclusion that this connection requires a pci-e raid controller, but there is no pci-e on the board, and the other type of controllers I could not find. Also I had a thought - there are several hard drives from which only one always works, the others are in standby, when the first one is full there is a switch to another and so on until the last one, after which the first one is pre-cleaned and becomes active. The problem is that I don't even know if such a system or raid controller exists, but instead of pci-e another input. The board has the following ports: 1 sata, 1 hdd power, 1 vga, 1 dmi, 2 usb, 1 ethernet, 1 audio in, 1 audio out, 8 video in, attach [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRxug.jpg)

Thanks in advance for any help. The system only supports up to 6 tb

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is your motherboard exact model?

Comment: Harrymc, https://help.annke.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000311641--Annke-Vision-Specification-of-DW81KD

Comment: Its not clear whether or not this devices' SATA controller supports port multipliers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_multiplier so Its hard to tell.

Comment: Frank Thomas, it does not, I checked with the seller, so I have a question about the possibility of connecting a raid controller without pci-e

Comment: *"There is a surveillance system with one sata input"* -- SATA is not an *"input"*.  SATA is an I/O interface, and you seem to be referring to a SATA *port* or *connector*.  [This item](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003334191340.html?ug_edm_item_id=1005003334191340&edm_click_module=alg_product_3_5797198620&creative_img_ind=2&creative_img_tpl=136182&tracelog=rowan&rowan_id1=aeug_edm_21931_1_en_US_2021-11-27&rowan_msg_id=geraCOWS_21931_$1976ef9fc6d64c468cf33fad1b0a93c8&ck=in_edm_other) resembles what you call a *"sata hub"*, and has no PCIe requirement.

Comment: Also note that PCIe Sata Devices usually use the Sata Controller and its lanes, even though you have plugged the drive in via PCIe. if the Sata controller doesn't have sufficient lanes, and doesn't support Port multiplier capabilities, neither a PCIe or SATA device will allow you to connect multiple disks to a single port.